# How can a PDE be solved using a Neural Network?

Tags: neural-network, pde

I have tried to search for a simple answer to this question, but all explanations are intended towards people who can understand numerical methods and PDEs. I have a computer science background and all papers seem like jargon. I have learned about and used machine learning algorithms for classification and regression problems related to images or normal tabular data (which has input features and target class). I have also used neural networks, but only as a black box for producing required outputs given some inputs, and tuning parameters for best accuracy.

I fail to understand, given a PDE to solve, *what* is the input to a neural network when the net is trained with some examples? In the language of machine learning, What are the examples and what are the input features? what are the parameters?

Any help to understand this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It of course depends on the type of PDE. Many PDE describe the evolution of a spatially distributed system over time. The state of such a system is defined by a value ***v***(**x**,t) that depends on a spatial variable ***x*** that is usually a vector and on time *t*. The value itself can be a vector as well.

Learning samples can consist of discrete values of the initial condition ***v***_i_0(**x**_i,0) and values ***v***_i_j(**x**_i,t_j) at later times. The initial values are presented to the network as inputs. The outputs of the (recurrent) network at later times *t_j* are then compared with the sample values to calculate the error.

Since PDE are often spatially homogeneous, it makes sense to use recurrent convolutional networks here. This is the same type that is often used in image processing.

The size of the convolutional kernel depends on the degree of spatial derivatives in your PDE:

The network needs to have at least one layer for each component of the value ***v***. Additional hidden layers might be required, especially if the PDE have higher temporal derivatives.

This is a very brief answer to a complex question but I hope that it points you to the right direction. I am also aware that I used som PDE jargon but I tried to reduce it to the absolute minimum.

Comment: thank you very much, things have started making sense after doing some more research and reading your answer. Can you explain more on "at least one layer for each component of the value v" using a simple PDE?

Comment: I have one more related question: I got from many articles that the curse of dimensionality is a problem in solving PDEs. I think the huge dimension they're referring to is the huge amount of learning samples? am I correct?

Comment: Concerning the number of layers: If the state of your PDE is described by a vector, for example the velocity components of a fluid, you need layers for the x, y and z components. At least if we assume that a cell output is a number.

Comment: By using a convolutional neural network, you can greatly reduce the number of variable weights. This means that you can also reduce the amount of training data. In some cases, you can get good results by training the network on a single initial condition with expected states given at a few values of t.

Answer (score 0):

Whereas you already have a general answer, I can provide a few links that might be helpful:

[2d heat equation solver based on tensorflow; in Russian only, but you should be able to do something with this](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/urtrial/pde/blob/master/partial_differential_equation.ipynb)

[another solver - looks like a 2d wave equation or smth - from the tensorflow developers](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/community/en/pdes.ipynb)

[ODE neural solver from the author(?) of the first project](https://github.com/msurtsukov/neural-ode)